# Composer - workaround for multiple versions of same package

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, composer-php

I am using Laravel 5.2 and it depends on Symfony/Process 3.0.*

I am looking to use Symfony/Process 3.1 to take advantage of the streaming the output of a process. Since composer can't install multiple versions of the same package, what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Did you try adding to your `composer.json` the specific package that you want to see if Laravel satisfies itself with that? If so, what error do you get?

Comment: Yes, and I received an error saying that Laravel is incompatible with 3.1

Comment: This is the error: Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.2.0 requires symfony/process 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/process[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v3.0.0, v3.0.0-BETA1, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: can you post your composer.json files?

Comment: can you switch to this https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/framework#5.3.x-dev ?

Comment: You can try forking laravel, setting Symfony/Process 3.1 as its dependency (instead of 3.0) and requiring this fork from your project. This solution is some kind of overhead but still you can consider it.

Comment: @Matteo Yes I think I'm just going to upgrade to 5.3 instead - Thanks!